# Multiple services implementing same interface, switching at runtime

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

I'm trying to create multiple services that all implement the same interface/contract, and which service that is used depends on user input. So I can do that in controller to get service that is selected from user.

Service Provider:

```
/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->call([$this, 'registerProductionService']);
}

/**
 * Produce video depend on user selection.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 */
public function registerProductionService(Request $request)
{
    $service = studly_case($request->input('production')) . 'Repository';

    if (in_array($service, $this->availableServices))
    {
        $namespace = (new \ReflectionClass(ReportContract::class))->getNamespaceName();

        $this->app->bind(ReportContract::class, "{$namespace}\\{$service}");
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
public function create(ReportContract $report)
{
    $report->create();
}
```

But when I want to call create() method from queue, I can't get data from Request class. It means I can't get service that is selected from user? So how can I do that?

Comment: It's a good question but I don't think you can do it at runtime with laravel services, which are registered in the service provider. That has to be loaded at bootstrap time. You may be able to achieve something similar in the middleware -- the middleware will have access to your request object and so should be able to initiate a binding between the interface and the implementation at that time.

Comment: I can't figure out with middleware. May you give me a example? Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it with a callback:

```
$this->app->bind(ReportContract::class, function($app) {
    $request = $app['request'];

    $service = studly_case($request->input('production')) . 'Repository';

    if (in_array($service, $this->availableServices))
    {
        $namespace = (new \ReflectionClass(ReportContract::class))->getNamespaceName();

        return $app->make("{$namespace}\\{$service}");
    }
});
```

You might want to return a default though.

Comment: It can't work, the $request->all() always return empty array.